# i want to create clicked face is marked and other faces are default color on second click

Tags: javascript

I have a feed back section where once a face is clicked it is marked with a specific color and other faces are defaulted to a second color in case the user click on another face (if he changes his mind).

```js
function feedback(tab_number) {
  document.getElementById('feedback-' + tab_number).classList.add('clicked');
}
```

```css
.feedback {
  /*background-color: darkgray;*/
  padding: 10px;
  width: fit-content;
}

i {
  margin: 10px;
  /*color: gold;*/
}

.default {
  color: black;
}

.clicked {
  color: gold;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="feedback">
  <i class="fas fa-angry fa-5x " id="feedback-1" onclick="feedback(1)"></i>

  <i class="fas fa-frown-open fa-5x " id="feedback-2" onclick="feedback(2)"></i>

  <i class="fas fa-smile fa-5x " id="feedback-3" onclick="feedback(3)"></i>

  <i class="fas fa-grin-stars  fa-5x " id="feedback-4" onclick="feedback(4)"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please clarify where the second click happens? If on another face, then do you want all to be default and this other one selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not very clear, but I think you might mean something like:

```js
function feedback(tab_number) {
  let clicked = document.querySelector("i.clicked");
  if (clicked) {
    clicked.classList.remove("clicked");
  }

  document.getElementById("feedback-" + tab_number).classList.add("clicked");
}
```

```css
.feedback {
  /*background-color: darkgray;*/
  padding: 10px;
  width: fit-content;
}

i {
  margin: 10px;
  /*color: gold;*/
}

.default {
  color: black;
}

.clicked {
  color: gold;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="feedback">
  <i class="fas fa-angry fa-5x " id="feedback-1" onclick="feedback(1)"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-frown-open fa-5x " id="feedback-2" onclick="feedback(2)"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-smile fa-5x " id="feedback-3" onclick="feedback(3)"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-grin-stars  fa-5x " id="feedback-4" onclick="feedback(4)"></i>
</div>
```

So, when you click on a different face, the previous highlighted face gets their `clicked` class removed from their class list and it gets added to the new clicked face's class list.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by checking if the `element.classList.contains('clicked')`. If it does, then it has already been clicked and then you need to remove the class `clicked`, otherwise add it.

**See below:**

**Note:** I've edited it further to provide functionality for removing and adding  class `clicked` to other faces automatically.

```js
function feedback(tab_number) { 
  let clickedElem = document.getElementById('feedback-' + tab_number);
  let add = false;
  
  if( !clickedElem.classList.contains('clicked') ) {
    add = true;
  }
  
  let elems = document.querySelectorAll(".feedback i");
  
  elems.forEach(function(el) {
    let currTabNum = el.id.substr(9, el.id.length);  // get the tab number
    
    if(add && currTabNum <= tab_number) {
      document.getElementById('feedback-' + currTabNum).classList.add('clicked');
    } else if(!add && currTabNum >= tab_number) {
      document.getElementById('feedback-' + currTabNum).classList.remove('clicked');
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.feedback {
  /*background-color: darkgray;*/
  padding: 10px;
  width: fit-content;
}

i {
  margin: 10px;
  /*color: gold;*/
}

.default {
  color: black;
}

.clicked {
  color: gold;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="feedback">
  <i class="fas fa-angry fa-5x " id="feedback-1" onclick="feedback(1)"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-frown-open fa-5x "  id="feedback-2" onclick="feedback(2)"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-smile fa-5x " id="feedback-3" onclick="feedback(3)"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-grin-stars  fa-5x " id="feedback-4" onclick="feedback(4)"></i>
</div>
```

Note:

Comment: @Naveen007 that's what I understood you wanted. My first version was then correct. Anyways, glad you found an answer that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
function feedback(tab_number){

  document.getElementById('feedback-1').classList.remove('clicked');
  document.getElementById('feedback-2').classList.remove('clicked');
  document.getElementById('feedback-3').classList.remove('clicked');
  document.getElementById('feedback-4').classList.remove('clicked');

  document.getElementById('feedback-' + tab_number).classList.add('clicked');


}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to know where you're going wrong:

1. You are dynamically fetching a `HTMLElement` by id, based on the value passed as the tab to your function. So when that element is fetched, you decorate it with a class `clicked`. The moment you click a different icon with a different tab number, the class `clicked` is not removed from the previous click. So Your DOM still has the class added based on the previous clicks.

---

I would approach this solution by doing the following.

```js
//  Get all Clickable Elements
var clickableElements = document.querySelectorAll('.clickable');

// Create a function that clears current state of the rating
function clearAllRatings(){
  // Loop through each clickable rating and clear it's clicked class decoration
  clickableElements.forEach(function(element)
  {
      element.classList.remove('clicked');
  });
}

//  Loop through each element
clickableElements.forEach(function(eachElement){
  // Add Click event to each element
  eachElement.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    // clear current rating
    clearAllRatings();
    // creat new rating
    event.target.classList.add('clicked');
  });
});
```

```css
.feedback {
  /*background-color: darkgray;*/
  padding: 10px;
  width: fit-content;
}

i {
  margin: 10px;
  /*color: gold;*/
}

.default {
  color: black;
}

.clicked {
  color: gold;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="feedback">
  <i class="fas fa-angry fa-5x clickable" id="feedback-1"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-frown-open fa-5x clickable " id="feedback-2"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-smile fa-5x clickable " id="feedback-3"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-grin-stars  fa-5x clickable " id="feedback-4"></i>
</div>
```